# Using Magento, how do i get a jQuery script to load?

Tags: jquery, magento

So I'm trying to get the following jQuery code to load on our onepage checkout page... basically it should show a related-div when a text field is entered... however, it just won't load.  I've tried it in jsfiddle, and it works fine, but once on Magento, it won't work...

jQuery CODE

```
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict();

  jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery(".show-hidden-div").click(function() {
    jQuery('.hidden-div').css('display','none');
    var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
    jQuery("#tip-"+inputId+"").show();
});

});
</script>
```

The above code is entered directly into the head.phtml file

Here's a link to the jsfiddle that shows how it should work.... http://jsfiddle.net/PeTUy/8/

any insight would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However regarding to Magento and jQuery and Prototype usage:

1. include jQuery before any prototype scripts
2. add jQuery.noConflict(); directly to the end of your jQuery file to ensure it is always called before Prototype scripts and isolated properly

you need this to avoid protptype and jquery conflict as they both race for $ as method name

Comment: Hi Anton:  I have no problem using prototype, but to be quiet honest, I really don't know much about Prototype... I tried creating a jsfiddle with the code you provided, but it didn't seem to work...  http://jsfiddle.net/X6HgY/

Answer (score 3):

Magento doesn't include jQuery as default, you need to include the jQuery source first.

If you're not including jQuery already, here's a link that might help:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/268482/

Assuming you have done this, just a heads up that the benefit of using noConflict mode of jQuery is to redefine the variable used to select elements, like so:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and then using $j wherever you need it like this:

```
$j(document).ready(function(){

    $j(".selector).functionName();

});
```

That way, the standard "$" variable that jQuery uses doesn't conflict with the likes of prototype, that uses the same variable.

Comment: MIke... where would I add `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` ?   Would I just add this to bottom of the jquery file we have loaded? or should I add this as part of the script we are using?

Comment: I would recommend adding it as part of an init script and loading that script directly after you load jQuery. I use a file called `jquery-init.js` in `var/www/magento/js` to do this. make sure you add `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` at the very top of this file.